# JPQL, is there a way to filter a child collection without also filtering the parent which doesnt fullfill the condittion?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

A `Project` has a list of employees. An `Employee` has a set of projectEmployeeRole. A `ProjectEmployeeRole` is connected to one project.

I wanted to get a project, with all its employees and the projectEmployeeRoles of the employees in one request to avoid the N+1 problem.

Im able to do this with:

```
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project JOIN FETCH project.employees employees " +
       "LEFT JOIN FETCH employees.projectEmployeeRoles role " +
       "WHERE project.id = :id")
Project findProjectById(@Param("id") long id);
```

But i would like to only get the roles which project id is equal to the parameters project id. I tried doing:

```
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project JOIN FETCH project.employees employees " +
       "LEFT JOIN FETCH employees.projectEmployeeRoles role " +
       "WHERE project.id = :id AND role.project.id = :id")
Project findProjectById(@Param("id") long id);
```

This correctly only returned the roles which projects id is equal to the paramter, but the problem is that it did not return employees which dont have roles which fullfill this condition. I would like it to still return all employees of the project. Only the employees roles should be filtered. So employees which dont have any roles matching the condition, should still get returned with an empty set of roles.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: In SQL, instead of a LEFT JOIN you would simply RIGHT OUTER JOIN the roles to keep the employees without roles, but no clue if this is possible in JPQL. Is there a reason you don't simply load all employees and have a filter method on the entity filtering an employees roles by project returning the filtered list in Java instead of in SQL?

Comment: @Smutje Ye, i guess i could use the first SQL query posted to get the project with all its employees and all its roles. And then filter the roles in java afterwards. The problem i had with the first query is that it returned employees with N roles N times, instead of just once. So the employees list of the project had employee duplicates which is caused by the `LEFT JOIN FETCH employees.projectEmployeeRoles role` i think. It returns an employee for every role he has. Is there a way to only select `DISTINCT` employees? I could remove the duplicates in java aswell, but doesnt seem efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you should extend your query. Try something like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project" + 
       "JOIN FETCH project.employees employees " +
       "JOIN FETCH employees.projectEmployeeRoles role" +
       "JOIN FETCH role.project as roleproj" +
       "WHERE project.id = :id AND roleproj.id = :id")
Project findProjectById(@Param("id") long id);
```

Or this:

```java
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project" + 
       "JOIN FETCH project.employees employees " +
       "LEFT JOIN FETCH employees.projectEmployeeRoles role" +
       "JOIN FETCH role.project as roleproj" +
       "WHERE project.id = :id AND roleproj.id = :id")
Project findProjectById(@Param("id") long id);
```